# Laravel 8, creating zip file for all the images in public folder. Facing file error : ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Tags: laravel, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to zip all the files inside my public 'img' folder but I keep getting this error.
I have checked many posts on stack overflow and the code seems to be ok. I think I am missing something here. Can some one please help?

**ErrorException
ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object**

**Laravel version :  8.11.2**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use ZipArchive;
use File;

class DownloadController extends Controller
{
public function zipFile(){       

    $zipper = new ZipArchive();
    $filename = 'newzip.zip';
    
    if ($zipper->open(public_path($filename), ZipArchive::CREATE === TRUE))
    {
        $files = File::files(public_path('img'));        
        foreach($files as $key => $val){
           $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($val);
           $zipper->addFile($val, $relativeNameInZipFile);
        }
        $zipper->close();
    }
    return response()->download( public_path($filename));
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you are miss passing the arguments

change this:

```
if ($zipper->open(public_path($filename), ZipArchive::CREATE === TRUE))
```

to:

```
  if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
```

and try again

Comment: Hi, I have user this $zipper = new ZipArchive();  So $zip wont work

Comment: so just change it to $zipper :|

here you are:
if ($zipper->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)